# Using Dojo Toolkit with CakePHP

Tags: javascript, cakephp, dojo

I am developing a cakePHP application and I want to use Dojo toolkit, which is a javascript framework. I want to link dojo to my app. I followed following steps :

1) Added a "dojo1.9.3" folder(subfolders "dojo", "dojox", "digits") in app/webroot/js folder.

2) Created a view home2.ctp in app/view/page/ folder, which contains following code:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->script('/js/dojo-1.9.3/custom');
?>
<h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
```

3) Created custom.js file to use dojo:

```
require([
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/fx',
    'dojo/domReady!'
    ], function (dom, fx) {

        //Changing DOM Content
        var greeting = dom.byId('greeting');
        greeting.innerHTML += ' from Dojo!';

        //Adding Animations
        fx.slideTo({
            node : greeting,
            top : 300,
            left : 450,
        }).play();
    });
```

After accessing home2 page, above code should change the dom element h1 form displaying "Hello" to "hello from Dojo!", and animate it using dojo function. But its not working,it is only showing "Hello". The dojo code is working fine without cakePHP.

I have tried DojoCake library too, but it has following problems:
1) Its app folder has plural names for directory name, and cakephp has singular names.
2) After opening in localhost it is giving following error:

> Warning: include(cake\bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: But this is cakephp error. Is Your project configured correctly?

Comment: Looks like you didn't read manual and/or missed some installation onstructions. Are you sure you'd made everything right?

Comment: Yes I did, I am able to configure and make projects in dojo and cakePHP separately, But getting problems in integrating both. CakePHP prefers "Conventions over Configuration", and CakePHP's app directory has singular name for folders but DojoCake has Plural see : [DojoCake](https://github.com/LordZardeck/DojoCake)  .. So will that not be a problem ?

Comment: Can't I use Dojo Toolkit in cakePHP just as other javascript libraries? or It is dependent on DojoCake ?

Answer (score 2):

This-

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->script('/js/dojo-1.9.3/custom');
?>
```

should be as-

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->script('dojo-1.9.3/custom');
?>
```